# Get all URL list while visiting web pages

Tags: excel, list, url, web-scraping

Is there any tool of webservice to get url listed in Excel while visiting webpages?

For example if I go to any website which contains Page 1-2-3-4-Next  Now if I click on any page then the URL of that particular page will be listed or in table.

I want to crawl some data from a website so I need the URL list.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of selenium IDE plugin in firefox, for recording your required actions. Automatic code will be generated based on your selection (java/perl/python/php). you can save the code and modify the code for getting the URL's and proceed as you like. This is the answer for your Question.. Personally i will not recommend this approach you are following

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Site Visualizer](http://site-visualizer.com/en/). Create new project, click *Start* button to crawl a website. All its pages will be listed in the *Pages* table (at the top of the main window). Click through a page to get all its links to be listed in the *Links* table (at the bottom of the window):

[image]